# Error: expected ')' before 'data'

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, header

I am trying to set up a PriorityQueue template class that will store Nodes within a vector. I am currently working on the Node class and running into a couple of errors related to the two constructors that I have for my Node class.

Here is the error that I'm getting:

Comment: For greater efficiency for complex types, use the initialization list in the constructor and pass the input by const reference (or by value and use `std::move` in C++11). Also why does your front function return a copy and not a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit

```
typename PriorityQueue<T>::template Node<T>::Node(T data, int *index, float priority)
```

should be

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T data, int *index, float priority)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what syntax you are trying to use to define the template class constructor, but it should look like this:

```
template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T data, int *index, float priority)
{
    // ...
}
```

Further, you should consider using an initializer list to initialize the object's members.